# Limitations of email to sms vs an sms api

Tags: email, twilio, sms, sms-gateway

Configuring an appointment app and looking at using email to sms. The api is significantly less expensive as you just have to look up the mobile number once, get the appropriate carrier gateway address(once for every new number), and then send an email that is converted to sms via the provider. As opposed to getting charged for every sms sent.

Why is this approach much less common? I've never really seen it. I figure there must be some limitations or issues that everyone else knows about that I couldn't find.

Note: Not sending out bulk messages. It's an appointment reminder for small businesses, not used for email marketing and such.

Comment: Prone to significant carrier filtering (not designed for the above use case), only P2P (peer-to-peer communications).

Comment: Interesting... anywhere I can find out to what extent they filter, etc?

Comment: The filtering is done by the carriers terminating the SMS. They have AI that looks for patterns of text and decide based on patterns what is SPAM (unwanted traffic) or A2P over a P2P route. All business to consumer traffic is considered A2P traffic and should not be sent over this type of route. Reference CTIA Best Practices - https://www.ctia.org/the-wireless-industry/industry-commitments/messaging-interoperability-sms-mms. In particular, Non-Consumer (A2P). The recommendation today, until 10DLC is more common, is to use a TF number to successfully send A2P traffic with minimal filtering.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me!